Broadcast message: The system will suspend now!
I think it is the KUbuntu 24.04's new feature, that I'm getting
Broadcast message: The system will suspend now!
in my ssh session.
I found one solution that disable sleep for bash, somehow it works, but my KUbuntu display never goes off after that either.
My system's previous and my hoping behavior is, my KUbuntu display goes off after 5 minutes, but my ssh session stays active (or the whole system entirely all the time, if that's simpler).
I've checked KUbuntu's System Settings, but wasn't able to find a setting for my desired behavior.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


Happened to me yesterday on an Ubuntu 24.04 that was recently upgraded from 22.04 and had never shown this problem before. After the due curse of events, I saw that Reddit has a quick solution (in turn coming from the Debian forums).
